# Write comment and add WorkItem In Pending Changes window

Tags: tfs, vsix

I want to add comment and workitem by code with a Extension of Visual Studio. I look for the command to do the job. Does it have API or else to access TFS controls in VS.

[image: Pending changes]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) to do this. And you can get some examples from this blog: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/tag/tfs-api/